# How to use shortcode in php code to get value via shortcode for php code?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode

I'm trying to get postid via shortcode to get parent category of that post.
Here is my code

I tried this code for now but not get any luck, I don't know what is going wrong. Please consider my request I'm very new to PHP and WordPress.

```
<?php
    $category_detail=get_the_category('[field parent-id]');//$post->ID
    foreach($category_detail as $cd){
        echo $cd->cat_name;
    }
?>
```

I want to print my post id like this

```
$category_detail=get_the_category('4');//$post->ID
```

I can't use PHP code to get post id as my other format is make with shortcodes so please help me in this. Thanks (Sorry for poor English)

Update : I tried this code also but no luck

```
<?php
    $id = do_shortcode('[field parent-id]');

    $category_detail=get_the_category($id);//$post->ID
    foreach($category_detail as $cd){
        echo $cd->cat_name;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is [field parent-id] a custom shortcode you wrote? If you are just trying to get the current posts parent you don't need a shortcode for this?

Comment: @RustyBadRobot i used "Plugin: Custom Content Shortcode " I use these short codes on other template so thats why i need this.

Comment: @RustyBadRobot any help? thanks you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this shortcode is trying to get the parent-id, but the parent ID of what? You need to tell It, so try this (untested)

```
global $post;
$parent = $post->post_parent;
$id = do_shortcode('[field '.$parent.']');
$category_detail=get_the_category($id);//$post->ID
foreach($category_detail as $cd){
  echo $cd->cat_name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help , the short code define by plugin as if i paste it without php its work and show parent post id, but its not work when i use it in php on same page . i cant use your above code as my shortcode start loop for posts and the parent post fetch by shortcode is correct for correct post, your code get other id and meanwhile i tried your code also  i got blank page and when i remove global $post; then data show for other short codes  but php code not work. any other way ? thanks again